# ProvidePlugin with webpack

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

I would like use global function with webpack. So i've create `myModule.js` :

```
function test() {
  return 'test';
}
```

and in my webpack config :

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      'moment': 'moment',
      'test': 'myModule'
    })
  ]
```

If i test this configuration, i've error :

```
Cannot resolve module 'myModule'
```

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 0):

```
'test': 'myModule'
```

would make it look for `node_modules/myModule`. You'd likely want to do

```
'test': path.join(__dirname, 'myModule')
```

so it looks like the file itself, rather than the node module.

Comment: Hi logan. Thank for your response. I've test with this : `'test': '../private/js/myModule.js'` but no result (Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'). My webpack config is on /build/ folder.

Comment: You'd need to use `__dirname`. If you use a relative path, it will be relative to the file you are using it in, which isn't right.